# Command to Delete Millions of Files From Directory

Tags: files, rm

I have directory which contains millions of files of small size (output from a big data program). I need to delete those directories but when I type the standard `rm *` I get:

```
zsh: sure you want to delete more than 100 files in data/output [yn]? y
zsh: argument list too long: rm
```

The files all have the same prefix with a unique number appended after like this

```
data-12343
data-12344
... etc
```

So I can't even use regular expressions to trash the files in a piecemeal way. Looking for advice and tips on how to do this efficiently and in an automated way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `xargs` to run your `rm` command. It will re-run `rm`, using up the maximum number of arguments each time, until it has completed your original intention of `*`.

In the words of the man page:

> The command line for command is built up until it reaches a system-defined limit (unless the -n and -L options are used).  The specified command will
>          be invoked as many times as necessary to use up the list of input items.  In general, there will be many fewer invocations of command than there were
>          items  in  the  input.  This will normally have significant performance benefits.  Some commands can usefully be executed in parallel too; see the -P
>          option.

Comment: Great. I just did `ls | xargs rm` and it did the trick!

Comment: @M.K. although that worked in this case, you shouldn't rely on the output of `ls` for things like this: a better option would be `printf './%s\0' * | xargs -0 rm`. Please refer to [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Similar to @steeldriver's comment, another option would be to use `find` and pipe the results to `xargs` like so: `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm`

Comment: @steeldriver if `rm *` failed why would `printf ... *` work?

Comment: @roaima I believe it's because (at least in `zsh`, which the OP is using, and `bash`) `printf` is a shell builtin and so not subject to the `ARG_MAX` limit